# Junit 4 assertEquals(...) fails to compare two objects

Tags: java, whitespace, junit4

Error message:

```
Expected: UserDTO<UserDTO{username='user', password='password', email='mail@mail'}> 
Actual: UserDTO<UserDTO{username='user', password='password', email='mail@mail'}>
```

The only difference is a whitespace after the '>' of the expected stringified object.
I do not know why, because i compare two UserDTO objects.
Has anyone had the same issue?

UPDATE:
The equals implementation of UserDTO.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserDTO userDTO = (UserDTO) o;

        if (username != null ? !username.equals(userDTO.username) : userDTO.username != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(userDTO.password) : userDTO.password != null) return false;
        return  (email != null ? !email.equals(userDTO.email) : userDTO.email != null);

    }
```

Comment: Does UserDTO implement #equals and #hashCode?

Comment: What is the actual line of code where you are making this assertion? e.g. `assertEquals(expected, actual)`?

Comment: @konsolas Yes, default implementation of intellij.

Comment: Is UserDTO your own class or part of a library? Assuming the former, what do you mean by "default implementation of intellij"? Did you autogenerate #equals and #hashcode? Did you make sure you only included the "user" "password" and "email" fields?

Comment: @AndyTurner 
assertEquals(userDTO1, userDTO2); where the two objects are equal. I tested it with userDTO1.equals(userDTO2).

Comment: @AxelBrunnbauer maybe you should post the UserDTO code here.

Comment: @AxelBrunnbauer so you're saying that `assertTrue(userDTO1.equals(userDTO2))` passes, but`assertEquals(userDTO1, userDTO2);` does not?

Comment: [That doesn't seem possible](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L110-L134)

Comment: The logic is reversed in the last line of your `equals` method.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, you are right. Weird, since i autogenerated these methods to avoid such mistakes. Obviously i must have changed that code somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison failure message gives you a state of objects  what you expect and what you get.
The fact that the two objects show the same state but that these are not equals for `assertEquals()` means that the `equals()` method doesn't rely on the value of the declared fields or it may also means that `equals()` contains logic error(s) .

And for you it is the second case as this :

```
 return  (email != null ? !email.equals(userDTO.email) : userDTO.email != null);
```

should be :

```
return  (email != null ? email.equals(userDTO.email) : userDTO.email == null);
```

as if `email` is not `null`, you want to return the `equals()` result on this field while if `email` is `null`, you want to `return` `true` if `other.email == null` and `false` otherwise.

Anyway, the `equals()` method could be much simplified by using `Objects.equals()` to compare each field as it spares you from doing a `null` check for each field :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    UserDTO userDTO = (UserDTO) o;
    return (Objects.equal(username, userDTO.username) && Objects.equal(password, userDTO.password) && Objects.equal(email, userDTO.email));        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
return  (email != null ? !email.equals(userDTO.email) : userDTO.email != null);
```

returns false if the emails are equal, and true if they are unequal.

You mean something like this:

```
return (email==null ? userDTO.email==null : email.equals(userDTO.email));
```

Comment: "You mean something like this:" Or, stick with the pattern of the two lines above, and return true as a final statement: `if (condition1) return false; if (condition2) return false; if (condition3) return false; return true;`.